# SQL server Import CSV file - 1'st row is also added as s column name

Tags: sql-server, import, csv

I'm trying to import a CSV file using import export wizard, Im facing an issue.
The first row is also added as a column name.

**Import wizard:**

[image]

The highlighted area is my 1'st row.

Comment: What is your row terminator?

Comment: THis is my row delimiter {CR}{LF}

Comment: can you check if the csv file first row has the CRLF at the end?

Comment: I have attached the snap in my question, can you check whether it has or not?

Comment: I can't do it from a snap :), copy the first two rows when opening in notepad, and check if there is a CRLF at the end, if not that is your issue.

Comment: OK, while opening in notepad it looks like col1, col2, col3, row1 :(

Comment: Your source file is wrong, get it edited and things should work fine

Comment: Ok, I have few more files which are in 100GB, so is this possible to edit while importing to SQL Server?

Comment: You can use SSIS and try skipping the rows that are not working and writing them to another file and later manually importing them?

Answer (score 1):

I used your data and was able to do it without any issues. Seems your first row of data does not have {CR}{LF}. The snap of data looks like there is an auto new line rather than you providing it.And that is why the 3rd column has ' Is_Active""1, so the wizard is looking for a comma now. Below is my test with data of similar type :

[image]

[image]

[image]